# Create 3d map for fps game - Three.js

Tags: 3d, three.js, webgl

I would like to create a 3d map like in Counter-Strike games, with Three.js, but I don't know in which format to create it? What tool should I use to create it?

Comment: You should really do some research, stackoverflow is here to help you with problems to your current solution, you don't yet have such a solution.

Comment: Map is not a 3d object, it's a simple 2d image, and player is drawn on it by calculating his position in 3d according to the map's coordinates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a really good example of a 3d map created using three.js canvas renderer:
http://www.virtual3ds.com/matt_evans

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about three.js, but recently i've worked with mentioned game format and have some info about it.

If you want to create map for games like Counter Strike the best way is to create a text file in *.map format, recognized by Valve Hammer Editor. Editor might be used to compile map to the compiled binary format (after you add some lights, entities..etc).

Text Map file format is described here:

https://developer.valvesoftware.com/wiki/MAP_file_format

What is interesting - the data isn't stored in typical 3d data format like most of 3d data exchange formats (which stores directly faces or quads with texture information). The Valve Map file format stores informations about clip planes that allows to create particular part of the model. Also coordinate system isn't real (not meters or units like that), so you have to calibrate your model into the game units.

So simple wall (8 corners, 6 quads) **is solid, that is clipped from 6 directions and require to have 6 plane definition data**.

Unfortunatelly it isn't simple task, because having quad/faces information you have to analyze wireframe model and combine it into the solids (volume data), that can be used to split into the target data - clip planes.

In my opinion the solution is:

- **You have to find way to convert created model to solid model defined by the clip planes.**
- In the next step, you have to write it in valve map format, and import it in Valve Hammer Editor.
- In the next step you can compile the map with Editor to the binary map format (i assume you configure zhlt tools for bsp map compilation), that will be recognized by game.